# How can I post a video to Facebook and let members of a group view it?

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups, facebook-videos

I have a video I filmed for a group that should ideally only be viewable to those people.  How can I post a video to Facebook and let members of a group view it?  If my friends can view it, that's acceptable, but there are members of the group who aren't on my list, so I'm not sure if they'll be able to see it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you post a video to a group then all members of the group will be able to see the video.  If the group is open then *anyone* who views the group will be able to see the video.

[From the Facebook FAQ](http://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=12611)

> **How do I post videos to a group?**
>
> Group admins can select whether videos
>   can be posted to a group from the
>   Customize tab of the Edit Group page.
>   If videos are enabled, the admins have
>   the choice to allow either all group
>   members or only other admins to post
>   videos.
>
> If you are allowed to add videos, you
>   can do this by clicking the "Video"
>   icon in the Publisher at the top of
>   the group’s main page. If this is an
>   open group, the videos will be visible
>   to everyone who views the group. The
>   videos posted on closed and secret
>   groups are only visible to other
>   members. Admins always have the
>   ability to remove videos that they do
>   not want to be associated with their
>   group

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions about the Customize tab. Unfortunately, I can't find any customize tab. Any more specific suggestion of where to find it? I go to the Edit Group part... then there's nothing about videos.